# understanding whether to use protocol or inheritance (or both?)

Tags: objective-c

I have a type of object in my game that simply moves horizontally..  It has a method like this:

```
-(void)moveLeftWithBlock:(void(^)())block {
    self.targetX = self.position.x - MOVE_AMOUNT;
    id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.125f position:ccp(self.targetX, self.targetY)];
    id ease   = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:4];
    [self runAction: [CCSequence actions: ease,
                  [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:block], nil]];
}
```

...

Now, I wanted to make a second type of object that's exactly the same, except that it can also move vertically...  My initial thought was to just subclass that object's class, and overwrite the moveLeftWithBlock and update its targetY..  but not only do I not like that solution because I still end up with 99% duplicate code amongst the two classes, but also because my game needs the Y position set prior to that moveLeftWithBlock method being called.

So next I thought-- Ok, so I can make my game call a prepareToMove method, which could do any kind of setup that might be required...  For the main object type, nothing..  For this 2nd object type, set the targetY.

However, I immediately started thinking-- wait----  I know protocols are about explicitly defining methods that are OPTIONAL or REQUIRED, and it made me think that perhaps I should be utilizing this here, but I just am not sure how.

So, can anyone explain to me how a protocol could be used in this case-- and if it is "the way to go" or not?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these would work. You could add to this andAlsoMoveVertically: (bool) isVertical and then add the vertical movement in an if statement in the function.